# I need a little guidance on creating a snap package

Tags: packaging, python3, snap

I'm planning to create a snap on my python3 app trespass (password keeper).
I host it on github https://github.com/gps1539/trespass and it can be installed from pypi via pip install trespass.

I think the install should be simple as it just needs to import the following python modules numpy, pygmgme, argparse and pyperclip. I found that pip install of pygmgme fails as gpgme.h is missing, so it also needs to apt-get install python3-gpgme

I've registered it as a snap but I need a little guidance on how to best structure the install and then write the yaml file.

- How do I state python3-gpgme as a dependency and make sure this done 1st?
- Is it better to use snap to invoke pip install or
- directly pull it from github, then apt-get install the dependencies
- although it is a small file, it there a way/need to chksum the downloads

Attaching a link PKGBUILD file I use to build it on Arch linux https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=trespass

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for snapping a python application can be found in the [snapcraft docs python language guide](https://docs.snapcraft.io/build-snaps/python). This should get you started. If you get stuck, ask further questions here, or join us on #snappy irc or the [snapcraft forums](https://forum.snapcraft.io/). I'm keen to hear your feedback on how you get on with that guide!

Comment: Many thanks, the guide looks to be very well written. I will report back in a few days.

Comment: Popey, still having issue and I tried to  to copy my yaml, setup.py and the output of 'tree' to the forum page to try to get some help and I got flagged "too many links" or something like that.  I'll try the irc?

Comment: posted questions here for help    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232260/looking-for-help-in-creating-a-snap-package and                                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233365/looking-for-help-in-creating-a-snap-package-part-2